# How can I check if a file exist in a index file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can I check if a physical file is located in index file?

For example:

Let's say we have 5 files in the folder `C:\Users`.

I have a file with a link to this location

`C:\Users\1.txt`
`C:\Users\2.txt`
`C:\Users\3.txt`
`C:\Users\4.txt`

We can see that we are missing 1 file from `C:\Users` in that index file?

How can I do it? If you could give me some way to do it, it would be great. Is it even possible to do such thing?

Comment: So what's the problem? Reading filenames from a file? Checking if a specific name exists in a directory?

Comment: I want to check if a index file has all index from physical file location.  For example if C:\Users\ has 2 file. I want to make sure it is in a index file location.txt.

Comment: Yes and I want to know what the problem is. Your question will get downvoted/ignored/closed if you don't state at what specific part you have run into a problem.

Comment: I think I just realized how I can solve it. I can read each file in that location create a index file and compare? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path = "C:\Users"
for file_item in os.listdirs(path):
    file_item_full = path + "/" + file_item
    #check if the file_item_full name exists in the index file
```

i would do it like this, you can first read the file and add all lines in a list so you are not reading all the times the index file.